# Can we give test case name as title of screenshot in protractor?

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

from **protractorConfig.js** :

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
  baseDirectory: './reports/'+outputFolder+'/screenshots',
  takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
}));
```

There is an option, docTitle, but not sure how to fetch test case name as title here....

Answer (score 1):

In jasmine 1.3, it's:

```
jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description
```

In jasmine 2.x, the reporter would be able to access the description name.